# error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files

Tags: c, gcc

How to fix this error?

I am trying to compile the C project, but I get such error

```
Alekseys-MBP:mmn14 aleksey$ make
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c -o assembler.o assembler.c
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c -o utils.o utils.c
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c -o symbol_table.o symbol_table.c
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c -o file_scan.o file_scan.c
file_scan.c:323:2: warning: no newline at end of file [-Wnewline-eof]
}
 ^
1 warning generated.
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c -o data_block.o data_block.c
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c -o commands.o commands.c
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic assembler.o utils.o symbol_table.o file_scan.o utils.h data_block.o commands.o -o assembler 
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
make: *** [assembler] Error 1
```

there is my `makefile`

```
EXEC_FILE = assembler
C_FILES = assembler.c utils.c symbol_table.c file_scan.c utils.h data_block.c commands.c
H_FILES = common.h symbol_table.h data_block.h commands.h file_scan.h

O_FILES = $(C_FILES:.c=.o)

all: $(EXEC_FILE)
$(EXEC_FILE): $(O_FILES) 
    gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic $(O_FILES) -o $(EXEC_FILE) 
%.o: %.c $(H_FILES)
    gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c -o $@ $<
clean:
    rm -f *.o $(EXEC_FILE)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a header in your source file list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This list of C files:

```
C_FILES = assembler.c utils.c symbol_table.c file_scan.c utils.h data_block.c commands.c
```

contains a header, file `utils.h`.

When this statement:

```
O_FILES = $(C_FILES:.c=.o)
```

constructs the list of object files, the substitution `.c=.o` does not alter `utils.h`, which results in `O_FILES` containing a header file. Then this build command:

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic $(O_FILES) -o $(EXEC_FILE)
```

asks GCC to do its default actions with the files, which is to link the object files and write an executable file and to “precompile” (analyze) the header file and write a “precompiled header” data file. Thus, you have two output files.

To fix this, remove `utils.h` from `C_FILES` and put it in `H_FILES`.